# Dynamically make data frame value column name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to get a value in a column to set as the column name. The characters that come before a colon should be the column name.

```
df = cbind.data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5),
    characteristics_ch1 = c("gender: Female", "gender: Male", "gender: Female", "gender: Male", "gender: Female"),
    characteristics_ch1.1 = c("Thing One: a", "Thing One: a", "Thing One: a", "Thing One: b", "Thing One: b"),
    characteristics_ch1.2 = c("age: 60", "age: 45", "age: 63", "age: 56", "age: 65"))
```

For columns 2-5 I'd like to remove "gender: ", "Thing One: ", and "age: " making them the name of their respective columns.

The resulting data frame would be:

```
Result = cbind.data.frame(
        id = c(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5),
        gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"),
        `Thing One` = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
        age = c("60", "45", "63", "56", "65")
)
```

To do this I'm running the following function:

```
re_col = function(i){
        new_name = str_split_fixed(i, ": ", 2)[1]
        return(assign(new_name, str_split_fixed(i, ": ", 2)[,2]))
}
```

Through the following applying functions:

```
plyr::colwise(re_col)(df)

#and

purrr::map(df, re_col)
```

Without success.

There could also be a much better approach. I initially tried to write a function that could be used with dplyr in data cleaning as a %>% step but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `gather` the data frame to long-format, `separate` the value column by `:`, and then `spread` the data frame back to wide-format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -id) %>%
  separate(Value, into = c("New_Column", "Value"), sep = ": ") %>%
  select(-Column) %>%
  spread(New_Column, Value, convert = TRUE)
df2
#   id age gender Thing One
# 1  1  60 Female         a
# 2  2  45   Male         a
# 3  3  63 Female         a
# 4  4  56   Male         b
# 5  5  65 Female         b
```

Comment: Awesome! This is an amazingly simple solution, wish I had thought of it!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, using `stringi` to split the data-values by a regex pattern supplied to whichever columns specified

```
rename.df_cols <- function(df, rgx_pattern = NULL, col_idx = NULL,...){
    if(max(col_idx) > ncol(df)){
        col_idx <- min(col_idx):ncol(df)
    }
    o <- lapply(col_idx, function(i){
    
        parts <- stri_split_regex(df[[i]], rgx_pattern, simplify = T)
        col_name <- unique(parts[,1])
        new_dat <- parts[,2]
        
        colnames(df)[[i]] <<- col_name
        df[[i]] <<- new_dat
    })
    return(df)
}

> df
  id characteristics_ch1 characteristics_ch1.1 characteristics_ch1.2
1  1      gender: Female          Thing One: a               age: 60
2  2        gender: Male          Thing One: a               age: 45
3  3      gender: Female          Thing One: a               age: 63
4  4        gender: Male          Thing One: b               age: 56
5  5      gender: Female          Thing One: b               age: 65
> rename.df_cols(df = df, col_idx = 2:4, rgx_pattern = "(\\s+)?\\:(\\s+)?")
  id gender Thing One age
1  1 Female         a  60
2  2   Male         a  45
3  3 Female         a  63
4  4   Male         b  56
5  5 Female         b  65
```

Is that what you're looking for?

#### EDIT with pipe:

```
> df %>% rename.df_cols(rgx_pattern = "(\\s+)?\\:(\\s+)?", col_idx = 2:5)
  id gender Thing One age
1  1 Female         a  60
2  2   Male         a  45
3  3 Female         a  63
4  4   Male         b  56
5  5 Female         b  65
```